# phone call using intent in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to call a phone number without using any permission in manifest.xml?

I'm usign below code, but it want to use call permission :

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "0" + getItem(pos).getMobile()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open up the dialer with a phone number already typed in it -

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "0" + getItem(pos).getMobile()));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

But for you to be able to call a phone directly from  a button click or something, you ***will*** need to add the permission, because if you're doing so, it means that ***your app*** is making the call, for which it needs permission from the android operating system.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` or `Intent.VIEW` needs no any permission, it only open the dealer app. On the other hand, `Intent.ACTION_CALL` will call directly and it needs call permission.

Answer (score 0):

sms

```
       Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

call

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_CALL );
    callIntent.setData( Uri.parse( "tel:" + phone ) );
    startActivity( callIntent );
```

permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Need a try in risk of crash?

Answer (score 0):

// You Just Try it I hope its work perfectly:
// Without permission android not permit you to make a call

// permission ""

```
    val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
    callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:" + "8809617016205")
    callIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            activity!!, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
        ) !==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity!!,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
            0
        )
    } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            activity!!,
            android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
        )
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Permission is granted
        activity!!.startActivity(callIntent)
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(activity!!, "Allow Your Phone Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer and it's from 5 years ago. Although you've added the code for using the permission properly, it is not easy to read, uses !! where it shouldn't and both the text and code have formatting issues. It needs some editing if you want it to be upvoted as a better option than the accepted answer.